Apache Beam | window kafka into text
Generator: create a taxi object with information about the taxi and push into kafka producer.
Splitter: custome UDF that split each batch of events into single event.
Partitioner: Partition the data by the taxi kind attribute.
In the following pipline I want to run on all of the partitions and push into Kafka topic (which works) and write into a file.
However I get Value error with windowing although I'm using Windowing.
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    partitions = ( 
        p
        | "Read from Kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={
                "bootstrap.servers": os.getenv(
                    "BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS",
                    "host.docker.internal:29092",
                ),
                "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
                "group.id": "kafka-io",
            },
            topics=[TOPIC]
        )
        | 'DecodeMessageValue' >> beam.ParDo(DecodeAndExtractEventsFn())
        | 'Windowing' >>  beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.FixedWindows(WINDOW_SIZE),
        )
        | 'PartionData' >> beam.Partition(parition_into_topic, len(KINDS))
    )
    for i, (topic, partition) in enumerate(zip(KINDS, partitions)):
        _ = partition \
            | f"Encripte-{i}" >> beam.Map(encode) \
            | f"writeIntoKafka-{i}" >> WriteToKafka(
                producer_config={
                    "bootstrap.servers": os.getenv(
                        "BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS",
                        "host.docker.internal:29092",
                    ),
                },
                topic=topic,
            )
        _ = partition | f"WriteToFile-{i}" >> beam.io.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='./output', file_name_suffix='.out')

Error:
ValueError: GroupByKey cannot be applied to an unbounded PCollection with global windowing and a default trigger


